# Where clause not working in a (before-insert) trigger which sets value to to a column from a different table

Tags: mysql, triggers, where-clause

I am creating a new trigger which inherits the value of new.base_price from a table named stockinfo which contains the details of the companyID and modelID of a bike. I want to inherit the new.base_price of only the entered data so I put where condition but it's not working for some reason...

> ```
> mysql> create trigger bi_sales
>     -> before insert on salerecord
>     -> for each row
>     -> set
>     -> new.base_price = stockinfo.saleprice where new.companyid=stockinfo.companyid AND new.modelid = stockinfo.modelid,
>     -> new.price = new.base_price - ((new.discount_in_percent / 100) * new.base_price),
>     -> new.loan = new.price - new.downpayment,
>     -> new.emi = new.loan / new.loandurationinmonths;
>     -> end;//
> ```
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'where new.companyid=stockinfo.companyid AND
>   new.modelid = stockinfo.modelid, new' at line 5

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - as it stands, you've not actually asked a question, or provided any information for us to help you.

Comment: Your query cannot see stockinfo because you haven't selected from this table..

Comment: I tried adding "FROM stockinfo" but still won't work. What should be done?

Comment: Thanks so much! I was in a hurry so did not copy delimiter information :D

Answer (score 0):

Apart from not selecting there are some other problems with the trigger try

```
drop trigger if exists bi_sales;
delimiter $$
create trigger bi_sales
   before insert on salerecord
   for each row
   begin
      set new.base_price = (select stockinfo.saleprice from stockinfo where new.companyid=stockinfo.companyid AND new.modelid = stockinfo.modelid);
     set new.price = new.base_price - ((new.discount_in_percent / 100) * new.base_price);
     set new.loan = new.price - new.downpayment;
     set new.emi = new.loan / new.loandurationinmonths;
    end $$

delimiter ;
```